# iam:CreateRole: Access Denied for assumed role

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

I am trying to create IAM role using an assumed role. Below is my terraform snippet.

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
  shared_credentials_file = "${pathexpand("~/.aws/credentials")}"
  profile                 = "default"

  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/Admin"
}
```

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "execution" {
  name               = "${var.name_prefix}-task-execution-role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.task_assume.json

  tags = var.tags
}
```

Where `name_prefix` has the value `DataScientists`
When applying this, I am getting the following error

```
Error: error creating IAM role (task-role): AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:sts::1234567890:assumed-role/Admin is not authorized to perform iam:CreateRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/DataScientists-task-execution-role
status code: 403,
```

I have given iam:CreateRole permissions in the IAM policy that is attached to Admin role. Yet I am getting the error.

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
"Action": [
                "iam:CreateRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/Data*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": "AllowCreateRoles"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the policy you've attached is allowing to create any `Data*` role within `1234567890` account. The error says your role name is `task-role`. So your policy should allow creating that role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/task-role",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": "AllowCreateRoles"
     }
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question. My bad that I have confused the roles in the question. Now this should make sense.

Comment: Ok, then policy seems to be correct. Did you check that it was properly attached to Admin role? How Admin role was created? Also in terraform?

Comment: policy is attached correctly to the admin role. It was not created via Terraform.